# Reverse DNS Resolve for MX record

Tags: domain-name-system, gentoo, reverse-dns

I've two servers running, one is a webserver and it's A record on my (external) DNS provider is in the form of:

**example.com in A XXX.XX.XXX.171**

The other is a mailserver and it's A record is in the form:

**mail.example.com in A XXX.XX.XXX.170**

and it's mx record is in the form:

**example.com in MX 10 mail.example.com**

How should my DNS reverse (i.e. my ISP provider) resolve:

**example.com** or **mail.example.com**?

BTW, this is how my */etc/hosts* file looks like:

```
127.0.0.1   mail.example.com mail example.com
::1     mail.example.com mail example.com
```

Thanks in advance for all the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have both of them matched exactly. i.e.

```
171 IN PTR example.com.
170 IN PTR mail.example.com.
```

In fact you can just copy and paste that to your ISP; that's exactly how it will look in their bind (DNS server) configuration.

Comment: Thanks very much. In fact did it, seems like it gonna take a while to process everything.

Answer (score 1):

You want the reverse DNS record to be for mail.example.com